# SQL Group by Date split into multiple columns depending on number

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table that stores notifications that i send out. It stores the ID of the notification, the Date when the notification was sent and the Number of notifications that have been sent with this id.

I want to generate a view that **counts** all first, second and third notifications and groups them by date.

Here is what i want to achieve. This is the table i have:

```
+----+------------------+--------------------+
| ID |    NotifiedOn    | NotificationNumber |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | 01.01.2000 00:00 |                  1 |
|  2 | 01.01.2000 00:00 |                  1 |
|  3 | 01.01.2000 00:00 |                  1 |
|  4 | 01.01.2000 00:00 |                  2 |
|  5 | 01.01.2000 00:00 |                  2 |
|  6 | 01.01.2000 00:00 |                  2 |
|  7 | 01.01.2000 00:00 |                  3 |
|  8 | 01.01.2000 00:00 |                  3 |
|  1 | 02.01.2000 00:00 |                  2 |
|  2 | 02.01.2000 00:00 |                  2 |
|  3 | 02.01.2000 00:00 |                  2 |
|  4 | 02.01.2000 00:00 |                  3 |
|  5 | 02.01.2000 00:00 |                  3 |
|  6 | 02.01.2000 00:00 |                  3 |
|  9 | 02.01.2000 00:00 |                  1 |
| 10 | 02.01.2000 00:00 |                  1 |
| 11 | 03.01.2000 00:00 |                  1 |
| 12 | 03.01.2000 00:00 |                  1 |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
```

Just to explain, for example: On the 01.01.2000 a user with the id 8 received its 3rd Notification.

This is what i want to get:

```
+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|       Date       | FirstNotification | SecondNotification | ThirdNotification |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 01.01.2000 00:00 |                 3 |                  3 |                 2 |
| 02.01.2000 00:00 |                 2 |                  3 |                 3 |
| 03.01.2000 00:00 |                 2 |                  - |                 - |
+------------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I don't really know i to go about that. If anyone could help i'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select notifiedon,
       sum(case when NotificationNumber = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as nofication_1,
       sum(case when NotificationNumber = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as nofication_2,
       sum(case when NotificationNumber = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as nofication_3
from t
group by notifiedon
order by notifiedon;
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will not work you have dynamic `NotificationNumber`. You need to use `PIVOT`.